# Linux command "which" doesn't locate executable files on NFS path under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs, which

I noticed the Linux shell command 'which' does NOT show an executable file although it is alredy on the search path.

More specifically, my $PATH includes '~/.local/bin'; an executable file is ~/.local/bin/charm. 'which charm' returns nothing although I can run 'charm' with no problem. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and bash

The issue depends on Linux distribution. If I log on to another machine of RHEL 6.10, the command 'which charm' works fine for the same executable.

The issue may also relate to nfs mount. On Ubuntu 16.04, the command 'which' seems to work fine for executables on local disks, for example, 'which which' shows '/usr/bin/which', but it does NOT find execuatables on nfs paths, which is the case for my '~/.local/bin'.

I searched online but couldn't find exaplaination. Is there a way to make the command 'which' under Ubuntu show all mached executables on path including nfs mounts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$PATH` includes `~/.local/bin` where tilde hasn't been expanded. `bash` will expand it on the fly each time, but `which` (at least on Ubuntu) or `sh` won't.

If you want `which` to see the executables in `~/.local/bin` you need to make sure tilde is expanded *before* the `PATH` variable gets it. The string `~/.local/bin` is probably added to your `PATH` by one of the startup scripts. Find the relevant line and fix it according to the examples below.

---

<sub>Note: first run each of the following examples in a fresh shell, so you can observe (`echo "$PATH"`) how it changes the variable each time independently.</sub>

This won't expand tilde character (because of quoting):

```
PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

This will:

```
PATH=~/".local/bin:$PATH"
```

Or this:

```
PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Rules of tilde expansion are somewhat complicated. Consider using `$HOME`. Examples:

```
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
```

---

To fix an already established `PATH` variable, replace `~` in it with the content of `$HOME`:

```
PATH="${PATH/\~/$HOME}"
```

Comment: Thank you Kamil! Either removing the quotation mark or manually expanding the tilde solved the problem. Great explaination!   so this has nothing to do with nfs, but does have some dependency on the Linux distribution.